# Вытянуть массивы через slice()

Tags: javascript

Помогите, есть массив с массивами(летний спорт, зимний, и фрукты как вытащить отдельно их через slice()?

```
sports = [
    ['skier','⛷'],
    ['snowboarder',''],
    ['apple',''],
    ['hockey',''],
    ['ice skate','⛸'],
    ['swimmer',''],
    ['surfer','‍'],
    ['watermelon',''],
    ['lemon',''],
    ['rowboat',''],
    ['bicyclist','‍']
];
```

Comment: вам картинки по названию получить надо, или любыми способами приплести сюда slice ?

Comment: отделить сами массивы (1,2,4,5)(6,7,10,11) и отдельно (3,8,9) через slice()

Comment: а использование slice это условие задачи, или вы про него где-то просто слышали и решили во чтобы то ни стало применить?

Comment: Да. Просто слайс вырезает кусок но как вырезать элементы если они идут не подряд.

Comment: вырежьте несколько раз. если не подряд.

Comment: sports.slice(...) + sports.slice(...)так?

Comment: console.log(sports[6].slice(0,6)) тут выводит слово surfer

Comment: немного не то. мне нужно вывести не одно слово а данные массивы как-бы сортировать по видам спорта зимним и летним и отдельно фрукты.

Comment: @YaroslavBiehliarov Это никак невозможно, если заранее нет три отдельных группы (массива) с названиями спортов и фруктов. Без этого скрипт не может вдруг узнать, что хоккей - это спорт)

Comment: их нужно выделить в новые массивы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

сначало с помощю join делаем одномерный массив потом можешь с помощю indexOf искать слово slice, понять под каким индексом он и вырезать slice-ом

```js
sports = [
    ['skier','⛷'],
    ['snowboarder',''],
    ['apple',''],
    ['hockey',''],
    ['ice skate','⛸'],
    ['swimmer',''],
    ['surfer','‍'],
    ['watermelon',''],
    ['lemon',''],
    ['rowboat',''],
    ['bicyclist','‍']
];
console.log(sports.join("").indexOf("surfer"))
console.log(sports.join("").slice(59,65))
```